# Getting PropertyInfo from expression tree does not give overridden property

Tags: c#, reflection

I get an expression tree from a lambda expression (using `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`) to get the PropertyInfo of a property which is overridden in a sub-class. It seems that this technique always gives me the PropertyInfo for the property in the base-class instead of the overridden property.

A work-around for getting hold of the correct PropertyInfo is to use reflection using the name of the original (wrong) PropertyInfo like so: `var correctPropertyInfo = mySubClassObject.GetType().GetProperty(wrongPropertyInfo.Name);`

Here is the code that illustrates this ([.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sWtsLr)):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var b = new B();

        var propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(b.GetProperty());
        Console.WriteLine("=== The wrong property ===");
        PrintProperty(propertyInfo);

        propertyInfo = b.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n=== The right property ===");
        PrintProperty(propertyInfo);
    }


    private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var expr = (MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body;
        return (PropertyInfo)expr.Member;
    }

    private static void PrintProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DeclaringType: " + propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
        Console.WriteLine("DisplayName: " + propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()?.DisplayName);
    }
}


public class A
{
    public virtual string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    [DisplayName("Overridden Method")]
    public override string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<string>> GetProperty()
    {
        return () => MyProperty;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
=== The wrong property ===
DeclaringType: A
DisplayName: 

=== The right property ===
DeclaringType: B
DisplayName: Overridden Method
```

Why am I getting the wrong PropertyInfo, and is there a way I can immediately get the correct one without the additional "work-around" step?

Comment: Please could you include the full code within the question instead of as a link? (Also, it looks like you're really talking about expression trees rather than delegates, so it's probably worth changing your title.)

Comment: Done. Thanks! :)